# What Modification?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

In the Expatriates "Top Questions" list, [this question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/15851/renewing-us-driving-license-while-living-in-uk-i-still-have-a-us-address-but-no) contains the text "modified 4 hours ago gnasher729." But when I open the question, I don't see any modification or comment since late 2019. Gnasher729's profile page, likewise, shows no action since January 2020.

What does the text mean? Is there a modification I cannot view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an answer [posted 2 days ago and deleted one minute later](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/posts/15851/timeline).  On a beta site like this one, you need 2k to view deleted answers, so this activity will be currently invisible to you.

Comment: Even if we can't see the deleted answers themselves, is there any reason for not allowing us to know that an answer has been deleted?

Comment: Thanks, gerrit.

Comment: @RayButterworth I don't know.  You could browse [Meta.SE] to see if this has ever been discussed or requested, and open a feature request if it hasn't been.